# "Undo" (delay) sending mails in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2011

Is there a way on Outlook for Mac to stop sending of recently "sent" outgoing mails?

[GMail undo](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1284885), and a [nice workaround for Outlook for Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/use-outlook-rules-to-prevent-oh-no-after-sending-emails/)  have pseudo-undo for mail send, that lets you catch a recently-written mail before it gets sent out to the audience (professional life-saver!)

Even the ability to have mails go out only on a schedule would work, but I can't figure out how to disable asynchronous sending.